# How to get value from DropdownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I cant figure out why Posted viewmodel not having selected values in DropdownListFor. Instead it is showing Ids in it.

In Controller HttpGet Edit Action:

```
      model.MaritalStatuses = new SelectList(maritalStatuses, "Key", "Value", 0);
     ---
     ---
    static Dictionary<int, string> maritalStatuses = new Dictionary<int, string>()
 {
        {0, "--Select One---"},
        {1, "Unmarried,"},
        {2, "Divorced, "},
        {3, "Widowed,  "},
        {4, "Separated,"},
        {5, "Annulled  "}
    };
```

View :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MaritalStatus, Model.MaritalStatuses,"--Select One--" , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In Controller HttpPost Edit Action:

```
     public ActionResult Edit(ProfileViewModel model)
            {
    ---
    // Here I get Keys in Property instead of Values in DropdownListFor
//For example : MaritalStatus =2    
---
    }
```

In ProfileViewModel:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
    {
---
---
 public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
        public SelectList MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
---
---
}
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SelectList`, it will be the key in your Dictionary that is `POST`ed when the form is submitted and not the value in your Dictionary. If you'd like the value submitted instead then use the string value as the key. Here's an example that builds the SelectListItem instances in the view (which I personally prefer to do):

```
static List<string> maritalStatuses = new List<string>()
{
    "Unmarried",
    "Divorced",
    "Widowed",
    "Separated",
    "Annulled"
};

public class ProfileViewModel
{

 public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

 public IList<string> MaritalStatuses { get { return maritalStatuses; } }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MaritalStatus, 
                      Model.MaritalStatuses.Select(s => new SelectListItem 
                          { 
                              Text = s, 
                              Value = s 
                          }, 
                      "--Select One--", 
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDs (Values) are unique whereas the description is not guaranteed to be unique so therefore cannot be relied upon for accurate selection information.

This is why a drop-down list will only ever return IDs (Value part of the drop-down). From there you can determine the text for each item as you populated the drop-down in the first place so must be able to tie them back up.